# Include Groups not having values for count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT DepartmentID
    , Count(EmployeeID) AS CountEmployee
FROM HR.EmployeeTransfer
GROUP BY DepartmentID
```

This is my current output:

```
DepartmentID CountEmployee
1            15
2            20
```

I want to include Departments which don't have any employees count like below:

```
DepartmentID CountEmployee
1            15
2            20
3            NULL
4            NULL
```

Comment: You need to start from your Departments table and `LEFT JOIN` to employees table.

Comment: @Larnu and if I don't have Employee table how can I achive that ?

Comment: You probably want one.

Comment: Do you have a `Department` table? What tables *do* you have, and what are there schemas and relationships?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you have a "departments" table of some sort.  For this query, you want a `LEFT JOIN` from this table:

```
SELECT d.DepartmentID, Count(et.EmployeeID) AS CountEmployee
FROM HR.Departments d LEFT JOIN
     HR.EmployeeTransfer et
     ON d.DepartmentID = et.DepartmentID
GROUP BY d.DepartmentID;
```

Note that this returns `0` instead of `NULL`.  If you really want `NULL`, you can use:

```
SELECT d.DepartmentID, NULLIF(Count(et.EmployeeID), 0) AS CountEmployee
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ET.DepartmentID
,Count(E.EmployeeID) AS CountEmployee
FROM HR.EmployeeTransfer AS ET
LEFT JOIN EmployeesTable AS E ON E.DepartmentID=ET.DepartmentID
GROUP BY ET.DepartmentID
```

Comment: and if I don't have Employee table how can I achive that ?

Comment: @MartinJames . . . I am lost on how this answers the question that you asked.  If if you had both tables, this would still fail to include the missing departments in `EmployeeTransfer`.